# Delete line from text file with line numbers from another file

Tags: linux, string, sed, awk, text-files

I have a text file containing a giant list of line numbers which I have to remove from another main file. Here's what my data looks like

lines.txt

```
1
2
4
5
22
36
400
...
```

and `documents.txt`

```
string1
string2
string3
...
```

If I had a short list of line numbers I could've easily used

`sed -i '1d,4d,5d' documents.txt`.

But there are lots of lots of line number that I have to delete. Also, I could use bash/perl  script to store the line numbers in an array and echo the lines which are not in the array. But I was wondering if there is a built in command to do just that.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation, and ignorant of the workings of sed, but if the file is modified in memory and you delete line 1, your old line 4 will now be the current line 3.

Comment: Why don't you use `sed` to also build the `'#d,...'` string?

Comment: @WesMiller That might be true, but if you use `sed -i` like I posted above, it will delete the specific lines and the line numbers will not shift like you mentioned.

Comment: @user946850 Iam not sure if I got your comment right but do you mean to reformat my lines.txt file to '<line>d, <line2>d' ? If that's what you meant .. damn I didnt think about it! Thank you for the tip! Upvoted!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

awk oneliner should work for you, see test below:

```
kent$  head lines.txt doc.txt 
==> lines.txt <==
1
3
5
7

==> doc.txt <==
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{l[$0];next;} !(FNR in l)' lines.txt doc.txt
b
d
f
h
```

as Levon suggested, I add some explanation:

```
awk                     # the awk command
 'NR==FNR{l[$0];next;}  # process the first file(lines.txt),save each line(the line# you want to delete) into an array "l"

 !(FNR in l)'           #now come to the 2nd file(doc.txt), if line number not in "l",print the line out
 lines.txt              # 1st argument, file:lines.txt
 docs.txt               # 2nd argument, file:doc.txt
```

Comment: It's always good to add some explanatory notes to one-liners. I'm a big fan of `awk` myself, but not everyone else who sees this may understand the magic.

Comment: True. But I think I got his code right. Chosen as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I speak no Perl and bash I develop painful trial after trial after trial.  However, Rexx would do this easily;

```
lines_to_delete = ""

do while lines( "lines.txt" )
   lines_to_delete = lines_to_delete linein( "lines.txt" )
end

n = 0
do while lines( "documents.txt" )
   line = linein( "documents.txt" )
   n = n + 1
   if ( wordpos( n, lines_to_delete ) == 0 )
      call lineout "temp_out,txt", line
end
```

This will leave your output in temp_out.txt which you may rename to documents.txt as desired.

Comment: thank you for your time. your answer certainly does the trick, but I prefer an awk or sed solution to writing a full blown code. in any case, have an upvote! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed ':a;${s/\n//g;s/^/sed \o47/;s/$/d\o47 documents.txt/;b};s/$/d\;/;N;ba' lines.txt | sh
```

It uses `sed` to build a `sed` command and pipes it to the shell to be executed. The resulting `sed` command simply looks like `sed '3d;5d;11d' documents.txt.

To build it the outer `sed` command adds a `d;` after each number, loops to the next line, branching back to the beginning (`N; ba`). When the last line is reached (`$`), all the newlines are removed, `sed '` is prepended and the final `d` and `' documents.txt` are appended. Then `b` branches out of the `:a` - `ba` loop to the end since no label is specified.

Here's how you can do it using `join` and `cat -n` (assuming that lines.txt is sorted):

```
join -t $'\v' -v 2 -o 2.2 lines.txt <(cat -n documents.txt | sed 's/^ *//;s/\t/\v/')
```

If lines.txt isn't sorted:

```
join -t $'\v' -v 2 -o 2.2 <(sort lines.txt) <(cat -n documents.txt | sed '^s/ *//;s/\t/\v/')
```

**Edit:**

Fixed a bug in the `join` commands in which the original versions only output the first word of each line in documents.txt.

Comment: this just clarified a lot of sed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/&d/' lines.txt | sed -i -f - documents.txt
```

or:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\n/d;/g;s/^/sed -i '\''/;s/$/d'\'' documents.txt/' lines.txt | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209404/filter-file-by-line-number) and got wonderful answers, among them the following awk script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# filterline keeps a subset of lines of a file.
#
# cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209404/376
#
set -eu -o pipefail

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: filterline FILE1 FILE2"
    echo
    echo "FILE1: one integer per line indicating line number, one-based, sorted"
    echo "FILE2: input file to filter"
    exit 1
fi

LIST="$1" LC_ALL=C awk '
  function nextline() {
    if ((getline n < list) <=0) exit
  }
  BEGIN{
    list = ENVIRON["LIST"]
    nextline()
  }
  NR == n {
    print
    nextline()
  }' < "$2"
```

And another C version, which is a bit more performant:

- https://github.com/miku/filterline