# sed delete lines from a logfile that respect numbers in another file

Tags: bash

I have a logfile that is starting to grow in size, and I need to remove certain lines that match a given pattern from it. I used `grep -nr` for extracting the target lines and copied them in a temp file, but I can't figure how can I tell `sed` to delete those lines from the log file. 
I have found something similar here: [Delete line from text file with line numbers from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369672/delete-line-from-text-file-with-line-numbers-from-another-file) but this doesn't actually delete the lines, it only prints the wanted output.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: just save the contents to another file and then rename it. `awk '{}' infile > outfile`

Comment: I believe `sed -i '/pattern/d' filename` is what you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, what you really need is `sed -i '/pattern/d' filename`.

But to answer your question:
How to delete lines matching the line numbers from another file:
(Assuming that there are no special characters in the line_numbers file, just numbers one per line...)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1; next}; !(FNR in a)' line_numbers input.log
```

Comment: i was aware of this, however it didn't workout for me. I realised that the solution was one layer lower. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a way of printing what you want to standard output, there's no reason why you can't just overwrite the original file. For example, to only print lines that don't match a pattern, you could use:

```
grep -v 'pattern' original > tmp && mv tmp original
```

This redirects the output of the `grep` command to a temporary file, then overwrites the original file. Any other solution that does this "in-place" is only pretending to do so, after all.

There are numerous other ways to do this, using sed [as suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230957/sed-delete-lines-from-a-logfile-that-respect-numbers-in-another-file#comment41142264_26230957), or awk:

```
awk '!/pattern/' original > tmp && mv tmp original
```

Comment: mv tmp original is not good if the logger keep the log file opened. In this case the orginal log file (that will continue to grow) will just be unamed. We have to change the content of the file, not the file (cat tmp >original and NOT link nor mv)

Comment: I hadn't considered the possibility that the file was still open or being written to but is the `cat`-based way guaranteed to guard against that?

Comment: cat modified the content of the file (the inode), not the link (name -> inode). That's why its behavior is different here (less efficient, but safer in some cases). If the file is still opened and if the other process appends lines concurrently, then obviously we can loose data. So "cat" is not a very good solution too. But I don't know a good solution in this case (but rotating log in the application and to NOT have have a file opened by someone else).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sed` and your file is growing continuously, then you will have to execute `sed -i '/REGEX/d' FILENAME` more frequently.

Instead, you can make use of `syslog-ng`. You just have to edit the `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf`, wherein you need to create/edit an appropriate filter (somewhat like: `f_example    { not match(REGEX); };`  ), save file, restart the service and you're done.

The messages containing that particular pattern will not be dumped in the log file. In this way, your file would not only stop growing, but also you need not process it periodically using `sed` or `grep`.

[Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/syslog-ng)

Answer (score 0):

To remove a line with sed, you can do:

```
sed "${line}d" <originalLogF >tmpF
```

If you want remove several lines, you can pass a sed script. Here I delete the first and the second lines:

```
sed '1d;2d' <originalLogF >tmpF
```

If your log file is big, you probably have two pass. The first one to generate the sed script in a file, and a second one to apply the sed script. But it will be more efficient to have only one pass if you be able to recognize the pattern directly (and do not use "${line}d" at all). See Tom Fenech or anishsane answers, I think it is what you really need.

By the way you have to preserve the inode (not only the file name) because most of logger keep the file opened. So the final command (if you don't use sed -i) should be:

```
cat tmpF >originalLogF
```

By the way, the "-i" option (sed) is NOT magic, sed will create a temporary buffer, so if we have concurrent append to the log file, you can loose some lines.